# Python and tkinter: NameError: global name 'roomChange' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\COMPUTER SCIENCE\Seating Plan\SeatingPlan TEST.py", line 205, in displayText
    if roomChange.get().strip() == "":
NameError: global name 'roomChange' is not defined
```

When attempting to run the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

def displayText():
    """ Display the Entry text value. """

    global roomChange


    if roomChange.get().strip() == "":
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Invalid Value", "Please enter a valid classroom name.")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Temporary Window", "Text value = " + roomChange.get().strip()) 

def roomChanger():

    chrm = Tk()
    chrm.title("Change Room")
    chrm.wm_iconbitmap('./Includes/icon.ico')
    chrm["padx"] = 40
    chrm["pady"] = 20       

    # Create a text frame to hold the text Label and the Entry widget
    textFrame = Frame(chrm)

    #Create a Label in textFrame
    roomChangeLabel = Label(textFrame)
    roomChangeLabel["text"] = "Enter name of classroom: "
    roomChangeLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

    # Create an Entry Widget in textFrame
    roomChange = Entry(textFrame)
    roomChange["width"] = 50
    roomChange.pack(side=LEFT)

    textFrame.pack()

    roomChangeButton = Button(chrm, text="Submit", command=displayText)
    roomChangeButton.pack() 

    chrm.mainloop()


testButton = Button(window, text='Change Room', command=roomChanger)
testButton.place(x = 825, y = 360)
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to my problem?
Thanks

Comment: you never assigned `roomChange` to anything you just globalized it

Comment: you should invest some effort to understand the error and investigate the problem before asking here.

Comment: @user4815162342: The way variables are marked as local or global in Python functions is not necessarily easy to Google for.

Comment: I did my best fixing your indentation; please verify things are correct now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed, but the question as stated doesn't demonstrate *any* effort to research or understand the exception, it just dumps the traceback and the code. That is clearly contrary to SO's charter.

Comment: @user4815162342: for this *specific* situation it's a complete lack of comprehension on the nature of Python scope handling, combined with a lack of knowing what terminology to look for. Sure, this question is not upvote worthy, but personally I am not voting to close it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `roomChanger()` you assign to `roomChange`:

```
roomChange = Entry(textFrame)
```

so you need to mark that name as a global inside that function too. Add a `global roomChange` statement in that function.

`displayText()` on the other hand, never tries to assign to `roomChange` and the `global` statement in that function can safely be removed.

Comment: Thank you, Martijn Pieters. And user4815162342, I've been working on it for a few hours now..

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.

Here was my solution:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Some sort of namespace glitch.  That second line shouldn't be necessary.  Technically from a syntax perspective `import *` implies import `messagebox` too because it's part of it all.

Use those two lines, take away `import tkinter.messagebox`

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with importing; this answer doesn't address the question that was asked.

Comment: @Jacob If you go to the tkinter folder on your hard drive (usually found at `C:\Pythonxx\Lib\tkinter`), you will see about a dozen or so .py's there. These files aren't automatically imported with the `from tkinter import *`. They have to be imported explicitly by name. This is why `from tkinter import messagebox` is required. For example, if you wanted the user to select a file from their computer, you might use `from tkinter import filedialog` to facilitate this.